# Error when Vagrant Up running?

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I am using vagrant on Ubuntu 14.04 and the version of it is **Vagrant 1.4.3**. When I am tiring to up the vagrant, Its giving me following error every time.

```
Successfully added box 'precise64' with provider 'virtualbox'!
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

shell provisioner:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: run
```

My virtualbox version = 4.3.10_Ubuntur93012

Please help me on this its blocking my every workflow :(

Comment: Do you use puppet provisioner ? You might want to upgrade to Vagrant 1.6. : https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/855

Comment: Could you post the provisioning part of Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of Vagrant on your Ubuntu machine (assuming 64-bit):

1. Remove your old version of Vagrant: `sudo apt-get remove vagrant`
2. Copy the Debian 64-bit download link from https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html
3. In your console, type `wget`, paste in the download link from step 2, and hit enter (should look like `wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/x.x.x/vagrant_x.x.x_x86_64.deb`)
4. Enter `sudo dpkg -i vagrant_x.x.x_x86_64.deb`, where `x.x.x` is the current Vagrant version

Credits:

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-vagrant-install-and-getting-started/
http://www.icchasethi.com/installing-latest-vagrant-and-virtualbox-version-on-ubuntu-12-01/